# Übersetzung von "meta-noise" ins Deutsche

Tags: meaning, english-to-german

Kontext: Vor kurzem, nachdem ich einen Beitrag bearbeitetet hatte (da ich wissen wollte warum dieser soviele Downvotes bekommen hat), wurde mir gesagt, dass ich den/die/das "meta-noise" doch bitte nicht hinzufügen soll.

Wie kann also der Begriff "meta-noise" ins Deutsche übersetzt werden? Falls es keine eindeutige Übersetzung gibt, währe eine  Umschreibung/Erklärung des Begriffes hilfreich.

(Ich habe als einzige Übersetzung "irrelevante Daten" gefunden, passt das in etwa?)

Comment: What were the changes you made?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. Edit your question to clarify and provide context. Do not post comments to clarify: not all comments may be initially shown and it's hard to dig through the comments to find out what you're actually asking. As is, your question is probably off-topic here, but you can ask it on [Meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's on how SO works, not about German language, so it should be on Mata.

Comment: @Robert But isn't this the right place asking for a translation? Or do you only mean the part asking for a definition?

Comment: atClose-Voters: Meaning of a word is on-topic, says the tag. Ironically, as you guys seem to read the comment, editing in this whole  context from a comment might be read as adding meta-noise about SE-workings? (@SomeWindowsUser That comment, its type, might usually end up in its own meta-post though.)

Comment: @SomeWindowsUser: vielleicht magst Du die Frage nach Deutsch übersetzen (als [edit], dann kommt es in die Reopen-Schleife), damit die Leute, die hier auf *off topic* votierten, besser sehen können, was Du genau wissen wolltest. Es geht Dir doch mehr um eine treffende  **Übersetzung** als um die Bedeutung im Englischen, oder?

Comment: Meaning of an *Anglizismus* and its "translation" into German, that's at home here. @SomeWindowsUser SO is StackOverflow, SE is StackExchange. You might try another [edit] to make it clear whether Robert is right (then this could be migrated) or my reading fits better (then I'll vote to re-open).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Communication is talking to someone about something.
Meta-communication is talking to someone about the communication itself.

Noise is here a concept from [communication theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_theory) as well, as in the pair "signal to noise", adapted from the [engineering concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio).
Signal is the meaningful information you want to get, noise is the rest of the communication that supposedly does not add any value to the topic at hand.

That leads us into the conundrum that meta-noise is quite often an oxymoron, talking about talking for clarification or establishing standards of understanding are not noise by definition, but in fact the opposite. Meta-communication is there to improve the signal as transmitted *and* received. Something vital in case of different languages, cultures etc.

This does not mean that meta-communication *may be perceived as superfluous* in certain situations that should be otherwise very clear cut. But in most cases I ever saw it is just a derogatory term.

<sub>While this answer is no statement about the quality of any post in particular or the "SE-model" as mentioned in a comment below the question. However, on SE sites it might indeed be better to not use meta-communication in a question or in an answer, as far as my humble understanding of that models goes. These meta-requests should really be made into comments or on the respective meta-sites. Conveniently, this paragraph with additional explanations might also serve as an example for perceived "meta-noise".</sub>

The suggested translation "irrelavante Daten" is not entirely bad, although *Daten* is quite abstract for meaning coherent words of a natural language.

One translation for this attempted refusal to communicate would be quite straightforward:
**"Meta-Rauschen".**

- "Meta" from the Greek is a [common prefix in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_griechischer_Wortst%C3%A4mme_in_deutschen_Fremdw%C3%B6rtern#M)  as well:

  > Bedeutungen
  >
  > 1. zwischen, inmitten, nach, nachher, später, ver… (im Sinne der Umwandlung, des Wechsels)
  > 2. drückt in Bildungen mit Substantiven aus, dass sich etw. auf einer höheren Stufe, Ebene befindet, darüber geordnet ist oder hinter etw. steht.
  >      <sub>From: DWDS.de [meta-](https://www.dwds.de/wb/meta-)</sub>
- "Rauschen"
  as the German translation usually used for "noise" in "signal to noise":

  > signal noise –– Rauschen,  Signalrauschen
  >   noise signal –– Störsignal,   Rauschsignal
  >   Examples:
  >   signal-to-noise ratio — Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis, Rauschabstand, Signalrauschabstand, Signal-Rausch-Abstand, Signal-Stör-Verhältnis
  >   (From: [Linguee: signal to noise](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/signal+to+noise.html))

Rauschen is a better fit since it uses existing concepts and translations thereof. It even is more naturally related to human language, especially when voiced.

Comment: Varför på engelska?

Comment: @CarstenS Die Frage wurde ursprünglich auf englisch gestellt, und später (_nach_ LangLangCs Antwort) auf deutsch umgeschrieben.

Comment: @Marzipanherz, I hadn't noticed, Danke.

Comment: @CarstenS Earlier versions of the question were posed in English. Your comment made me aware that the Q is now in German. Currently I just expanded it and I am now too time-constrained to translate the answer as well in a timely manner. Thanks for the heads up. Falls jemand zwischenzeitlich da ran will…

Comment: @LangLangC: ich hatte das vorgeschlagen, da die Close Voter offenbar der englischen Frage nicht so genau entnehmen konnten, was der OP wissen möchte. Eine Antwort auf Englisch halte ich aber hier für angemessen und völlig in Ordnung.

Comment: Ich finde das auch unproblematisch, ich hielt es nur zuerst für unmotiviert. Alles ist gut :)